# How to update openflow to 1.3

Tags: sdn, mininet, openflow, google-floodlight

I want to update openflow in my mininet from 1.0 to 1.2  or upper to run my flow pushers can anyone tell how to update it

since i get this error when push entries

```
ERROR [n.f.s.StaticFlowEntryPusher:Dispatcher: Thread-27] Apply Actions Instruction not supported in OpenFlow 1.0
```

e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running it from the command line with mn, you can add the parameter --switch ovs,protocols=OpenFlow13

i.e.

mn --switch ovs,protocols=OpenFlow13

if you are running it with a python script, you can pass the OF version in the remote controller:

```
from mininet.node import RemoteController
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.topo import LinearTopo

c0 = RemoteController('c0', ip=CONTROLLER_IP, port=CONTROLLER_PORT, protocols="OpenFlow13")

topo=LinearTopo(2)
net = Mininet(topo=topo,switch=OVSSwitch,build=False, cleanup=True)
net.addController(c0)
net.build()
net.start()
```